# Chrome 30 CSS HACK

Tags: css, google-chrome

Why does not  the css rules work in Chrome?

css:

```
.selector { (;property: value;); }
```

or

```
.selector { [;property: value;]; }
```

Comment: I think they don't work because it isn't valid CSS.

Comment: If you're using CSS hacks on modern web browsers, you're doing something seriously wrong. Seriously, tell us why you think you need a CSS hack for Chrome, and I'd be pretty certain that there will be a better solution for you.

Comment: @Spudley Yes,you are right.I didn't reset input's margin and padding and so on,but they have different values in firefox and chrome.So they have different affects to other html tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, this **isn't** a *hack*. Equally, this doesn't only apply to Chrome v30. The same functionality applies in all other modern browsers.

As defined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#block) in the CSS2.1 specification:

> ...parentheses (`( )`), brackets (`[ ]`), and braces (`{ }`) **must always occur in matching pairs** and may be nested.

When you add a `(`, for instance, Chrome will wait for the closing `)` before attempting to apply any styles. However, no CSS property is wrapped in parenthesis like this, so thus no style is applied.

Take this example:

```css
.selector {
    (color:#f00;); /* Invalid, ignored. */
    font-weight:Bold; /* Valid, not ignored. */
}
```

Here the `color` declaration is in parenthesis and the `font-weight` declaration isn't. Chrome will ignore the `color` property altogether as this is not a valid CSS declaration, but still process the `font-weight` as normal:

[image: Element Inspector]

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7TyZ/).

Parenthesis, brackets and braces like this are simply invalid CSS declarations and are ultimately ignored in the same way that the following would also achieve the same:

```css
.selector {
    color; /* Invalid, ignored. */
    font-weight:Bold; /* Valid, not ignored. */
}
```

It's also worth noting that Chrome will treat anything between parenthesis and brackets as a single CSS declaration. In your case, `(;property: value;);` is treated as one declaration, regardless of the extra semicolons.

It's also worth noting that if you fail to match the closing pair prior to ending the selector (with a `}`), any selector given after will not be processed ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/m7TyZ/2/)).

Answer (score 0):

That particular set of CSS oddities is actually known, and what is called bracket hacks for Safari (yes they have a name). They also worked in Chrome until version 28. It works in versions 7.0 and older in Safari at this time (version 8 is the current version of Safari as I am writing this update).